# How do I mark targets for remake using Open Watcom on the command line?

Tags: makefile, watcom

I can make my Open Watcom project like so:

```
wmake -f path/to/my/proj.mk -h -e
```

But how do I *RE*make, or mark files for remake? I looked at the `wmake` usage and nothing seems obvious there.

Does anyone know what the Open Watcom GUI does to "Mark for Remake"?

Comment: You either need to touch the source files (by using `wtouch` to "mark"  them by updating their last-modified time stamps to the current time) or delete all the files that makefile creates.  Normally with makefiles the standard practice is to create a `clean` rule that deletes everything the makefile creates.

Comment: This worked: `wtouch *.cpp` followed by `wmake` does a rebuild. Thanks, it was exactly the utility I was looking for.  Is there a reason you didn't put it in an answer?